# Why Space Element of Four Momentum Vector is 3 Momentum Vector?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, relativity

For example, if we look at the relation between space element of 4-velocity and 3-velocity; and space element of 4-force and 3-force

**$V = v\cdot\gamma(v)$**

**$F = f\cdot\gamma(v)$**

But why space element of 4-momentum vector is equal to 3-momentum vector?

**$P=p$**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but you could say it is because we defined $p$ (the lowercase one) already with a factor of $\gamma$: $p = \gamma m v$. If this $\gamma$ weren't there, then it would need to be present in your formula: $P = m v \cdot \gamma(v)$. The reason that we put the gamma in for $p$ is because that is the only way that momentum would be conserved.

Of course, as your question shows that you know, it is more natural to include $\gamma$ in the $V$ and $F$ as well, but this framework seems odd to people just starting to learn relativity, so instead relativity is taught basically using a galilean spacetime where velocities and forces are derivatives with respect to coordinate time instead of proper time. That is why the $V$ and $F$ formulas need $\gamma$s.

Comment: I understand why when F=f*(lorentz factor) if P=p and why V=v*(lorentz factor).
The part that i don't understand is why we define p=m*v*(lorentz factor). I mean you said "the reason that we put the gamma in for p is because that is the only way that momentum would be conserved." How can we conclude that if momentum must be conserved, we must add lorentz factor?

Comment: People collide really small particles together and they measure their velocities before and after the collision. The only way you can get momentum conservation to work it is if you put in that $\gamma$. If you leave out the $\gamma$, then the total $mv$ before the collision isn't equal to the total $mv$ after the collision.

Comment: So can we show why p equals to m*v*γ by using mathematical formulas?

Comment: No, at some point you will need input from the real world.

Comment: NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs,I found an essay that explains why it is relativistic momentum: http://arxiv.org/ftp/physics/papers/0404/0404059.pdf